# Active Admin Text Input are Big Instead of just a line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

this problem is across my rails app... The text input boxes are huge instead of simply being line ones.

in app/admin/restaurant.rb

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :name, required: true
    f.input :servesCuisine
    f.input :description
    f.input :currenciesAccepted, as: :select, collection:Restaurant.available_currencies
    f.input :priceRange, as: :select, collection: Restaurant.price_range
    f.input :paymentAccepted
    f.input :email, as: :email
    f.input :telephone, as: :phone
    f.input :faxNumber, as: :phone
    f.input :longitude
    f.input :latitude
    f.input :image, as: :file
  end
f.actions
end
```

[Huge texbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU4yH.png)

The problem also occurs on my login page where my email field is also gigantic. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use `as` option with `f.input` like -

```
f.input :servesCuisine, as: :string
f.input :description, as: :string
```

You can edit your `admin_users.rb` file

```
f.input :email, as: :string
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yep this fixes the issue for form fields, but how would go about fixing the login page? The email field also has this behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Thanks for helping
2. I don't have admin_users.rb I only have admin_user.rb in my /app/models and in there I don't have a form.
3. If this can help I am using Devise as an authentication method

Comment: have you defined these fields as text ? in other words what are the column types for same field ? string or text ?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, the login page I am talking about is the one automatically generated by devise therefore I do not know how the fields are defined.

Answer (score 1):

LHH is 100% spot-on, however if you need a bit more control but don't want to involve CSS, you can do:

```
f.input :title, label: 'Title tag', input_html: {cols: "5", rows: "1"}
```